# sharePoint online count unread message from office365

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, sharepoint, office365

As part of a project whose aim is to notably improve the visual side of a SharePoint Online site, I'm a bit stuck. On the home page in the left banner, users want to see the number of unread messages they have in Office365.

I created an area in the master page to put the result in. I thought the Rest API used to do this :

```
$.ajax ({
    type: "GET",
    url: " https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Folders/Inbox",
    dataType : "json",
    success : function (resp) {
        // count unread messages 
    },
    error : function (e) {
        alert (' Error121212 :' + JSON.stringify (e));
    }
 })
```

Unfortunately I get an error like cross domain. I tried with JSONP but it does not work either (uncaught syntax error unexpected token).

Can you please tell me if this is a good practice? I feel that it anyways I must find a technic for authentication. (In the case of JSONP I have a popup that asks me authentication and then problem occurs on callback apparently)...

I want to avoid developing a type requiring a typical deployment Wsp...

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL for the ajax request seems incorrect. The URL for getting the inbox messages via the API is: `https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/folders/inbox/messages`

Once you get the response, you can count the number of objects with the `IsRead` property set to `false` using a simple for loop and display that count.

Comment: I try this url but  unfortunately i have the same error : XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/folders/inbox/messages. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://url' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401. Do you know if it is possible to call the api from a another domain site? thx

Comment: The header should be set on the office365.com domain, so unfortunately, I don't think there is any way to circumvent this.

Comment: ok thks, i resigned, I think there is no simple solution to my problem , unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is related to CORS and how browsers refuse to handle cross-domain requests. To get around this, typically you would either

- Change the response header on the remote server - not an option here
- Use some sort of proxy to handle the requests - here's where SharePoint apps come in.

I know you stipulated that you want to avoid using a WSP style deployment but there simply isn't a way around it, you have to use the SharePoint App Model

[**This**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2012/11/29/solving-cross-domain-problems-in-apps-for-sharepoint.aspx) article goes a long way to answer your question, but for completion the basic steps are as follows

1. Create a SharePoint hosted app in Visual Studio
2. In the App Manifest, you need to define the trust relationship with the remote host (in this case the host of outlook.office365.com) using the AppManifest section
3. Use [SP.RequestExecutor.executor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn735924%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to make the request on your behalf

Comment: I had given up but I'll take it up again.
I'll read it . Thank you very much for this information.